# Apache SMTPClient connect times with gmail

Tags: java, smtp, apache-commons, apache-commons-net

All I did was this -

```
SMTPClient smtpClient = new SMTPClient();
smtpClient.connect(host);
int reply = smtpClient.getReplyCode();
if (!SMTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
    closeConnection(host);
    return false;
}

if (!smtpClient.login(SMTP_LOGIN)) {
    closeConnection(host);
    return false;
}
```

This is timing out in the connect call. In this specific case the host is "gmail.com".

Am I doing something wrong? Is something else needed to make connect work?

Comment: I might be missing something, but don't you need to provide the username and password for the `smtpClient` object to connect with?

Comment: I tried opening a connection with gmail.com (rather gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com) port 25 with telnet. That works ok. Anyway I only want to call vreify(some mail id) on this connection, in effect to verify if a gmail id is valid or not.

Comment: in case of gmail, you would need to use ssl or tsl that would mean verifying the port also (25 is not open I believe)

Comment: My mistake, just checked some example code and you don't have to provide the username / password prior to connecting - I'll post again if I find anything else.

Comment: @user3802077 As I mentioned in the comment, I don't know how to connect to gmail using the SMTPClient. As you mentioned, I was also doing a nslookup -q=mx gmail.com and then connecting to one of the non-authoritative clients on 25 port. Not sure how to do all these with standard libraries.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to do a MX lookup first (as I was doing with telnet).

This gives a nice [code sample](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0452.html) for this.